# print out only certain column between matching strings

Tags: awk, seq

input:

```
#word1  #word2  #word3  #word4
1.00     2.00    3.00    4.00
#end
#word1  #word3  #word4
11.00    13.00   14.00
#end
#word1  #word2  #word3  #word4
21.00    22.00   23.00   24.00
#end
#word1  #word3  #word4
31.00    33.00   34.00
#end
```

output:

```
#word1  #word3  #word4
1.00     3.00    4.00
#end
#word1  #word3  #word4
11.00    13.00   14.00
#end
#word1  #word3  #word4
21.00    23.00   24.00
#end
#word1  #word3  #word4
31.00    33.00   34.00
#end
```

What I like to do is to print out the certain lines between the matching strings. I can do it if all the same, but in input sometimes there are two columns, sometimes four columns. How can I get that output from the input?

Comment: If using awk, `print $1,$(NF-1),$NF` would probably work.

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts in their questions which they have put in order to.solve their own problem, kindly do so and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit column2 if the line has four columns, you can use

```
awk 'NF==4{ print $1,$3,$4; next }{ print }' input.txt
```

or shorter

```
awk 'NF==4{ print $1,$3,$4; next }1' input.txt
```

This prints columns 1, 3 and 4 if the line has four columns or the complete line otherwise.

Comment: @usermrt Would it be okay to format the output with `column -t`, i.e. `awk 'NF==4{ print $1,$3,$4; next }1' input.txt | column -t`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I like to know if I can select "matching string". Column is great but I will combine that code with mine. still appreciated for your answer

Comment: @usermrt, that's the reason we ask OP to add their efforts, now with your comment it completely looks like a new requirement, so please do add your efforts clearly in your question and let us know then.